# make string of N characters

Tags: php, string, repeat

Say I have a `number=20` and a `$value=7`.

If I want to make a string of 20 7's using PHP. what's the quickest way to make this?

So output like:

```
$a='77777777777777777777';
```

Any functions to make this easier?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
$a=str_repeat($value,$number);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php), e.g.

```
$a=str_repeat('7', 20);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/str_repeat):

```
$a = str_repeat('7', 20);
```

Answer (score 6):

[str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) is pretty easy

```
$a = str_repeat('7', 20);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$a = str_repeat('7', 20);
```

[`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

...or maybe:

```
$a = str_pad('', 20, '7');
```

[`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)